# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, xdocreport

Objective: Create a simple docx file and convert it into PDF.

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import java.io.*;

public class doc3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        //Start - Added Styles in word document
        XWPFStyles styles = document.createStyles();
        styles.setSpellingLanguage("English");
        CTFonts def = CTFonts.Factory.newInstance();
        styles.setDefaultFonts(def);
        //End
        XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun tmpRun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
        tmpRun.setText("Hellow World");
        tmpRun.setFontSize(18);
        File inFile = new File("test.docx");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inFile);
        document.write(out);
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
        //The error occurs in the below line. 
        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document,out,options);
        }
    }
```

The error that I receive is now as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:70)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:38)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.AbstractXWPFConverter.convert(AbstractXWPFConverter.java:45)
    at be.quodlibet.boxable.doc3.main(doc3.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.visitHeadersFooters(MasterPageManager.java:200)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.addSection(MasterPageManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.compute(MasterPageManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.MasterPageManager.initialize(MasterPageManager.java:90)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.visitBodyElements(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFDocumentVisitor.start(XWPFDocumentVisitor.java:199)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter.doConvert(PdfConverter.java:56)
    ... 8 more
```

I am not sure that am I missing something in PDFOption or something else.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Update:
Sharing the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.github.dhorions</groupId>
    <artifactId>boxable</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Boxable, a high-level API to creates table on top of Apache Pdfbox</name>
    <description>Easily creates tables in pdf.</description>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>ossrh</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableSshAgent>true</enableSshAgent>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                    <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                    <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                    <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                    <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.3</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                    <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                    <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: I use converter only with docx that I have created with MS Word. It seems that if you have no style, it causes problem, try to add (empty) style when you create your docx with Java  (never done that).

Comment: I have added styles into the word document and the code is updated.
Going forward, I got another issue... and the issue is updated. Its a null pointer exception error.

Convert the docx file to zip file. Extract it and go to word/document.xml. 
If we check there, It doesn't contains w:sectPr. This sectPr gives the width/height of the page.
For this we need to create the docx file in such a way that in the document.xml, the tag w:sectPr exists. Doing research on it.

Comment: "Doing research on it.": Yes that's what you have to do. But what this shows is, that it is definitely not a good idea when two projects which are not related to each other are using the same name space. `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf` **is not contained** in `apache poi` project. It is a `fr.opensagres.xdocreport` project.

Comment: ok..Thanks @Axel.
Do we have any class in Apache POI that can be used to convert docx to pdf.
I have used Apache POI project (`org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel`) to create a word document and by xdocreport project (`org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter`), I am trying to convert the docx to pdf.

Comment: "Do we have any class in Apache POI that can be used to convert docx to pdf.": No as far as I know. As you said, you need doing research on what lacks a `XWPFDocument` which is created from `apache poi` but what a `XWPFDocument` used from `xdocreport` necessarily needs. That's your part as developer because both projects are not taking care to each other.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue.

Rather creating the new file doc file converting it into PDF.

Just do one thing create a new file from MS Word as a template. Now try to create the file from it through Apache POI library.

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("template.docx"));
```

//create and add content in it

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newDocFileName.docx");
document.write(out);
out.close();
document.close();
```

Now try to convert it. You won't get this Null Pointer Exception.